# Bootstrap 5 Carousel Mask Effect

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I try to apply the masking effect for Carousel images at bootstrap 5 in the Django web project.

I tried many solutions but nothing work

this is the carousel

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" >
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
        <img src="{% static '.\images\home\sec1-1.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." >
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block ">
          <h1>Welcome to Markvira Agency</h1>
          <p>Smart digital marketing agency</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
      <img src="{% static '.\images\home\sec1-2.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h1>Welcome to Markvira Agency</h1>
          <p>Smart digital marketing agency</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

i tried the mask tag like this..but effect appear only at text are not mask the whole image slide

```html
<div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
  <img src="{% static '.\images\home\sec1-1.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." >
  <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)"> <!--Mask Tag-->
  <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block ">
    <h1>Welcome to Markvira Agency</h1>
    <p>Smart digital marketing agency</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make a gray layer over carousel images
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFUNO.png)

I hope you could help me
Thanks

Comment: It's an overlay effect. You can read and implement it from here - https://dev.to/ellen_dev/two-ways-to-achieve-an-image-colour-overlay-with-css-eio